# Getting data from Json for different Views

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've two buttons List View and Card View.

When i click on listview button i wanted to make a http call to fetch 20 data's. Same way i wanted to fetch 10 data when user hit's on  the card view.

So far i can able to display 10 records for both the view. I need some help to implement this feature.

I'm setting page-size = 10// Somehow i need to change the page-size to 20 when i'm in list view. Please help

```js
// i'm setting the page-size = 10 

fetchDynamic: function(amount, startingPoint, query) {
  var _this = this;

  function process(articles) {
    var convArt = [];

    for (var i = 0, len = articles.length; i < len; i++) {
      var article = articles[i];
      var trackerLabel;

      if (article.title) {
        trackerLabel = article.shortTitle.toString().split(' ');
        trackerLabel = trackerLabel[0] + '-' + trackerLabel[1] + '-' + trackerLabel[2];
      } else {
        trackerLabel = 'no title';
      }

      convArt.push({
        link: article.path,
        image: article.fileReference,
        label: article.contentTypeTitle[0],
        'date-time': moment(article.articleDate).format('DD MMMM YY'),
        title: article.shortTitle || '',
        desc: article.shortIntro || '',
        'link-desc': 'Keep reading',
        trackerEi: ++_this.trackerId + '-' + trackerLabel
      });
    }

    return convArt;
  }

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    query = query || '';
    var path = _this.options.path + '&page-size=' + amount + '&page-no=' + startingPoint + '&' + 'exact-match=true' + query;

    $.ajax(path, {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        _this.maximumResults = data.results;
        resolve(process(data.data));
      },
      error: function(err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Sample code doesn't mention 'list', 'card' or 'view', so cannot be answered.  At a guess though: `fetchDynamic(isListView ? 20 : 10, startingPoint, query)`